# Sphinx show values next to define macros

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen, documentation-generation

I am generating documentation for a C++ project using **Doxygen**, **doxyrest** and **Sphinx**. For Sphinx, I'm using the [Sphinx Book Theme](https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I wanted to know if there exists a possibility, when accessing a macro (`#define MAXIMUMSIZE 20`, for example) in the Sphinx documentation, to also see its value, and not only its name. To get more precise, when I navigate to the documentation page and look for `MAXIMUMSIZE`, it only shows it as a `#define MAXIMUMSIZE`, without also providing its value (20).

Doxygen provides its value automatically. Also tried changing to Sphinx RTD Theme, but I have the same problem. I don't think this has to do with the Sphinx themes, but with Sphinx itself.

Doxygen output:
[image]

Sphinx output: [image]

As you can see, in the second picture, `20` is missing.

Comment: Are you saying you want Sphinx to run C++ code and show the result? I don't know if that's possible. You can do that with Python notebooks or doctests.

Comment: @StevePiercy No. I don't want to run C++ code. I have some documented defines in my documentation, which in doxygen's generated HTML are shown in the form of `#define MAX 1024`, while Sphinx shows them as `#define MAX`. I also want that `1024` to be shown.

Comment: @StevePiercy I've updated the question with several pictures, in order to make it clearer.

Comment: I am using [breathe](https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as a bridge between Doxygen and Sphinx, there you can set `breathe_show_define_initializer = True` in the conf.py file to achieve what you want.